# Is it possible to set the default threshold for Fuzzy Select and Select > By Color?

Tags: gimp, default-settings

I use Fuzzy Select, and especially Select > By Color frequently. Both these have a "Threshold" value set in Tool Options as here:

[image: GIMP Toolbox showing the Tool Options for Fuzzy Select]

The default value of the Threshold is 15, but I most (very) frequently want to use a Threshold of 0.

**Is it possible to change the default value of Threshold for these selection tools to 0?**

I am using GIMP 2.8.22 on macOS 10.13.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set it to the value you want and go to `Edit>Preferences>Tool options` and click `Save tool options now`.

Note that this saves all current tool options for all tools, as well as the current tool, so you have better check out these options (or do this just after starting Gimp).

In addition you have mostly two strategies:

1. Always start Gimp with the same settings: untick `Save tool options on exit` and change your options with `Save tool options now` when necessary
2. Start with the options as set in the previous session: tick `Save tool options on exit`

Option 1) is usually better, unless you work on a single project for days...

For completeness, you can also save/retrieve preset options per tool using the Save/Restore icons at the bottom of the Tool options dialog.

Comment: AAAAAAHHHHHHH! OMG! Thank you! This has driven me up the walls for years. I had always assumed that highly-granular control over GIMP meant there was a place to modify and save specific default values, and the idea of saving the options together makes so much more sense. So I feel like a bit of an idiot, but a ***greatly relieved*** idiot. :)